# Confusion with trigger controlled analogue output of a DAQ board

Tags: trigger, data-acquisition

I came across [this](https://www.osapublishing.org/boe/fulltext.cfm?uri=boe-12-11-6701&id=460181) article, and regarding the DAQ trigger and analogue output part I'm confused.

If I don't get it wrong the DAQ generates particular analogue voltage levels for X and Y of the galvo-mirror. And [here](https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/370784k.pdf) is the manual for such DAQ series.

I'm used to control a DAQ output through software commands. But if I'm not mistaken here the DAQ produces specific varying voltages at each trigger. What kind of functionality is that? In my case I need to increase analog output from -10V to +10V at each trigger where the trigger will be sync to another device. So I dont want to control the DAQ analog output from SW but like the one in the article. It says:

> A DAQ device generates X- and Y-mirror position outputs for each laser
> line trigger. The galvanometer controller processes the input signals
> and outputs them to the mirrors.

But I haven't seen such control before. Could someone explain what really is happening here? How does the DAQ achieve that? Does that mean it was programmed to do so? But its not a microcontroller.

Comment: I can't see what DAQ you have on mobile (should really state this in your question), but what you're describing is a standard function on most NI DAQ boards. You would configure a PFI pin as your clock input and then advanced your DAC output one sample per clock cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I am on a PC, I can see you are asking about the NI X-series of DAQ cards. What you want to do is simple.

Assuming you have installed the NI DAQMX software, go to Start Menu -> National Instruments -> NI-DAQmx Examples.

Select the programming language of your choice.

Finally, since you want an analog voltage between -10V and +10V, select "Analog Out" -> "Generate Voltage".  Generating a voltage using an external clock would be the example in the folder "ContGenVoltageWfm_ExtClk".

Alternatively, since you pointed to a paper on laser scanning, you may want to use "ContGenVoltageWfm_ExtClkDigStart", which is the same thing, but with a start trigger.  If you are doing two dimensional imaging with a galvanometer scanner, you may need that start trigger to synchronize the scanner with whatever you are scanning (laser, camera, A/D, etc).  In the code examples, you can change both the clock input pin and the DAC output pins as needed.

As for "what is really happening here" you are telling the DAC to generate an analog waveform using the clock signal you provide.  There is no microcontroller involved, you're simply feeding a DAC a clock which it is using to make an analog signal. The code examples provide more detailed explanations for how this is configured.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it have Python support for such functionality in your case? Yes it will be about such scanning. But what concerns me  galvo might move fast for high scan rate(70kHz).  And what is the minimum delay I can introduce roughly between each DAC changes? Im asking because if the minimum delay is not short enough DAC will not move the galvo fast enough.

Comment: @user16307 I don't know if NI supports python, they can probably tell you. 70 KHz is slow for OCT scanning, so doubt you will be going too fast. The maximum sampling rate should be specified in the datasheet, but I believe it is a lot higher than 70 KHz.

Comment: Hi again. Is the thing you described hardware trigger? Is the routing of the external trigger to DAC happening internally? Im asking because if SW involved there will be delays.

Comment: @user16307 There is no software at all running, you are telling the device how to connect wires.. This is the standard design used on a lot of real-time imaging and OCT products, if there was delay beyond transistor rise times it would not work.

Comment: @user16307 How is that different than the example above?

Comment: @user16307 Yes I understand that that is what you want to do, and I think I answered that question last week when I showed you were to get the c# example code to move a galvanometer synchronously with an external clock. You said you were stuck and wanted more examples, but you didn't say what about the code confused you or how you got stuck. It is hard for me to help if I do not know what you are having trouble with.